# Something wrong in there I have to get true class average and write how many people gets A B C D F in the exams please help me?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Something wrong in there I have to get true class average and write how many people gets A B C D F in the exams.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int sum, stu, ort, grade, i;
  printf("how many students in the class?");
  scanf("%d", &stu);
  for (i = 1; i <= stu; i++) {
    printf("enter a score");
    scanf("%d", &grade);
    if (grade < 20)
      printf("Not: F\n", grade);
    else if (grade < 40)
      printf("Grade: D\n", grade);
    else if (grade < 60)
      printf("Grade: C\n", grade);
    else if (grade < 80)
      printf("Grade: B\n", grade);
    else if (grade < 100)
      printf("Grade: A\n", grade);
  }
  sum += grade;
  ort = (sum) / (stu);
  printf("medium= %d", ort);
}
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Initialize `sum` to zero.

Comment: "Something wrong" => is not a clear description of the problem

Comment: 1) `sum` needs to be initialized. 2)`sum += grade;` should go inside the loop.

Comment: I'd undoubtedly score 100. What would my grade be?

Comment: Step 1: get your book on statistics. Step 2: start counting. Step 3: print the results. This is a beginners assignment you should easily be able to solve. Besides, is a score of 100 not an A anymore?

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems, as I see it.

1. `sum` is not initilaized, so it's initial value is indeterminate.

   To elaborate, `sum` is an automatic-storage local variable and unless initialized explicitly, it contains indeterminate value.

   Now, seeing the usage here, `sum += grade;` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as per chapter  §6.3.2.1, `C11`

   > [....] If
   >   the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been
   >   declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object
   >   is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been
   >   performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.
2. The addition `sum += grade;` must be inside the loop. Otherwise, it will not be able to accumulate the entries from the loops.

That said, always check the return value of `scanf()` and family to ensure the success of the operation. Otherwise, you may end up with unspecified behaviour.

Comment: also I believe ort is better declared as float or double for the purpose

Answer (score 2):

```
if (grade < 20)
      printf("Not: F\n", grade);
    else if (grade < 40)
      printf("Grade: D\n", grade);
    else if (grade < 60)
      printf("Grade: C\n", grade);
    else if (grade < 80)
      printf("Grade: B\n", grade);
    else if (grade < 100)
      printf("Grade: A\n", grade);
```

in this part of the code you don't use grade at all. you need to delete the `, grade` part or to add `"%d"` inside the format.